# How to count number of Runs (not builds) in Netbeans (java)

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I have this which gives me number of Builds in the file build.num, but I want Runs!

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
<buildnumber file="build.num"/>
<manifest file="MANIFEST.MF">

    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyClass"/>
    <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${version}.${build.number}"/>

</manifest>
</target>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: so i have to count? how does like Microsoft keep track of their thousands of build numbers? Perhaps in a different programming language this is possible

Comment: You can't count runs; you can count builds.

Comment: In fact, you don't really count either. Your SCM counts versions and your CI counts builds. NetBeans is used to write code, not build it for production. This is obviously all _compile time_. Counting runs, as the name suggests, is _run time_. This has nothing to do with the SCM, the IDE or even the CI.

Comment: maybe write to a file on a server every time code is run.